# Our app crashes during startup - without exception, only "Send report"

Tags: wpf, exception, crash

Our app crashes during loading probably, only on some machines, I do not get any exception, only the windows "Send report" dialog.

Is there some way to get more information about what is causing the application to crash? 
In the "Send report" dialog, there is just:

AppName: evox.wpfclient.exe
AppVer: 1.0.0.0
ModName: kernel32.dll
ModVer: 5.1.2600.5781
Offset: 00012afb

Comment: I've seen similar crashes when required version of .NET is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event in your class that starts up your app.  Usually program.cs.

Add

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

then outside the main class

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ExceptionObject is Exception)
                _logger.FatalException("Unhandled exception", (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
            else
                _logger.Fatal("Unhandled exception: {0}", e.ExceptionObject);

            if (_program != null)
                _program.Exit();
        }
```

to the startup file and see if it catches your exception.  of course change the method to suit your purposes.

Comment: I am returning to this question after a long time. I did solve the problem after all, there was some compilation-bitness-related issue (I can't remember the details). What I want to point out is that we used a handler for UnhandledException event, but in this specific case, it was not called. The crash was so severe that the handle could not handle it :).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you do when your application launches, try subscribing to the event `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. In the event handler, you can log the exception before the application actually crashes.

If your application still crashes without logging, it's probably a problem with the .NET framework. In that case, you should see an event in the Windows Administration Tools Event Viewer.

Note: you should only use the UnhandledException event to log and then crash - don't try to recover and continue executing.